# A higher-order analogy to that if $f'$ is increasing on $\Bbb R$ except for countably many points, then $f$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, analytic-geometry, nonlinear-optimization, convex-geometry

It is well known that if a continuous function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable at all but countably many points and the derivative it increasing on its domain, then $f$ is convex. *Does its extension to "higher-order" convexity hold?*

> Consider $n \in \Bbb N_{\geq 2}$. If a function $f$ is $n-2$ times continuously differentiable and $n-1$ times differentiable at all but countably many points and $f^{(n-1)}$ is increasing on its domain then $f$ is *$n$-order convex*.
>
> > **Definition:** We say that a function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is **$n$-order convex** iff for all $x\in \mathbb R$ iff for any $a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_n$ the $n-1$ degree polynomial $p(x)$ interpolating the points $\big(a_1,f(a_1)\big),\ldots,\big(a_n,f(a_n)\big)$ is such that the graph of its restriction $p$ to $[a_{n-1},a_n]$ is contained in the epigraph $\mathop{epi}(f)$.

**Notes:**

1. According to the above definition, 2-order convex is identical to convex.
2. I got this question when trying relax the assumption that $f$ is $n$ times differentiable in the result: [Geometric characterization of the $n$-th derivative of $f$ being positive (convexity for $n=2$).](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4616713/1134951)
3. When $n=3$ this question is asking about the implication  Q1 $\Longrightarrow$ Q2 in the question [Geometric characterization of functions with positive third derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4617862/1134951).
4. The reverse implication is discussed in the post [A higher-order analogy to that every convex function is differentiable at all but countably many points](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4618033/1134951)

Comment: The statement in the first pargraph is false unless $f$ is assumed tio be continuous,

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks a lot for pointing it out! I also edited the statement of the claim.